# Stripe: "charge.succeeded" webhook not firing for connected account. Wrong event type name?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I suppose that a fundamental question I *really* ought to be asking, before I get into the details below, might be:

***As a vendor/service-provider with a standalone Stripe account that's been connected to a platform account, is it possible for me to set up a webhook that will be called when the platform makes a successful charge on my behalf?***

In any case, that's what I'm *trying* to do, with a webhook that I set up on the recipient account, configured to be called for any of the following events:

[image]

Test invocations of the webhook from my dashboard cause it to fire as expected.

But when when I [create a charge through the platform](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#charging-through-the-platform), setting `destination` to reference the connected account, the webhook doesn't fire -- even though the charge is successfully created, along with an accompanying event, in the connected account.

One big fat clue -- that I don't know how to interpret -- is that the *type* of the event shown in the dashboard's "Events & Webhooks" tab isn't `charge.succeeded` or `charge.captured` -- it's `payment.created` (!).

But:

- there's no event type with that name listed in the webhook configuration menu;
- nor, as far as I can tell, does the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api) define a `payment` object type (and indeed, the type of the object referenced in the event is `charge`):

[image]

**So:**

*Is this just a naming glitch in the API implementation that Stripe simply needs to fix?*

*Or is there some more fundamental problem that I'm failing to grasp with the idea of setting a webhook on a connected standalone account that I own?*

(Or am I just doin' it wrong?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the `payment.created` event is not visible in the list of selectable events, so you'd have to check "Send me all events" when creating the webhook endpoint in order to receive those.

Comment: I have this option selected and I still only get `payment.created` with my testing keys

Comment: Make sure you configured [webhooks](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/webhooks) for connected accounts as well if you use them of course. There are two sections in the dashboard `Endpoints receiving events from your account` and `Endpoints receiving events from Connect applications`

Answer (score 0):

extending Dmitry's comment in the post, I was able to solve it by adding my endpoint and webhook event type to **Endpoints receiving events from your account** section in the Stripe dashboard.

The other section called **Endpoints receiving events from Connect applications** is for events with a Connect Account associated with it. The [event object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object#event_object-account) will have an account property, as long as it is an event generated from a Connect Account. These events will go in the **Endpoints receiving events from Connect applications** section of the Webhooks page in the Dashboard.